# Textbox has no ScrollBar Property

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, scrollbar

Visual Studio's IntelliSense keeps blowing up at me when I try to set a vertical scrollbar on my textbox with C#. It says that 'TextBox' has no definition for Scrollbars and suggests that I'm missing something.

I think I must be missing something because everything I find online just assumes it works by typing `txtMyTextBox.Scrollbar = true;` but it doesn't work for me. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I haven't added any using statements, just the default that get loaded when using WPF, but no tutorials ever point to me needing to add one.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is a WPF project, correct?

Comment: "what I'm doing wrong" - you are using wrong property. TextBox doesn't have "Scrollbar" property. RTFM about TextBox

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox
    Height="200"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    Text="{Binding ... }"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```